# AzureAD using custom button click

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, blazor, blazor-server-side

Hello I'm trying develope demo with azure active directory (Blazor server app).

**My requirement:**

-> On click of button it should redirect on https://login.microsoftonline.com/ and it should authenticate user then it should again redirect to my current blazor app index url.

but after running blazor app it is directly redirecting to https://login.microsoftonline.com/ and after authentication page is redirecting to my application.

my code for looks like below:

**appSettings.json**

```
{
   "AzureAd": {
   "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
   "Domain": "jpda.onmicrosoft.com",
   "TenantId": "aacd4f65-xxxx",
   "ClientId": "93134054-xxxx",
   "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
   "ClientSecret": "I~Uoq5yxxxx"
},
  "Logging": {
  "LogLevel": {
  "Default": "Information",
  "Microsoft": "Warning",
  "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
 }
  },
 "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

**LoginDisplay.razor**

```
<AuthorizeView>
<Authorized>
    Hello, @context.User.Identity.Name!
    <a href="MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignOut">Log out</a>
</Authorized>
<NotAuthorized>
    <a href="MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignIn">Log in</a>
</NotAuthorized>
```

**Index.razor**

```
@page "/"

<div class="top-row px-4 auth">
 @if (IsButtonClicked == true)
 {
    <LoginDisplay />
 }
 <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank">About</a>
 </div>
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="(() => IsButtonClicked = true)">Login</button>

@code{ 
     [Parameter]
     public EventCallback<bool> OnButtonClicked { get; set; }
     public bool IsButtonClicked { get; set; }
  }
```

I'm calling  component conditionally from index.razor component, if button is clicked then and then it should call and redirect on authentication page.

if anyone have idea please help me!!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In azure when you go to

   > App registrations->new app registration

   After giving some valid name and  selecting valid tenant option,
   you can see Redirect URI option. Its important to put a uri there ,
   because once registered , you will have to get back to the
   application. The url depends on what is your application and where
   it is locally  resided.

   - After that when you go to authentication you can see the urls  that    you gave and you can add more.

   [image]

**2.** Open **startup.cs** . There must be something like below (There comment out lines shown below)

[image]

- Replace the following code in place of services.AddControllersWithViews(...) with below code to get redirected to login.microsoftonline.com on clicking signin button.

```js
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   //
   
   //
   services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

    services.AddControllersWithViews()
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

    services.AddRazorPages();
    
    
    
    //

    
}
```

**3.** In blazor , You can open **index.razor**  , Open **terminal** window
and add following Library =>Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
**Code :**

```
    > dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
```

[image]

**4.** You can open index.razor  and add the references like below. (You
may do this for the view that you like where you need authentication
to happen)

[image]

(Instead of giving authorization  in view ,you may also add [Authorize] attribute to the index action in your controller if your app has controllers)

### **References:**

1. [Redirect URI (reply URL) restrictions and limitations.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reply-url)
2. [Application configuration options.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-client-application-configuration#cloud-instance)
3. [Build a Blazor web app with Azure Active Directory authentication
   and Microsoft Graph.](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/identity/blogs/how-to-build-a-blazor-web-app-with-azure-active-directory-authentication-and-microsoft-graph/)

Comment: First of all thanks for your response!! I've figure out issue myself but now I'm facing another issue. I've already specified post logout redirect URI but still it's not redirecting me to my application url after logout. any idea???

Comment: Can you please check if [thread1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/357579/ad-b2c-post-logout-redirect-uri-not-working-on-bla.html) / [thread 2](https://github.com/dotnet/Scaffolding/issues/1287) is similar to your issue